# Font-not-found Helvetica Neue Light

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ubuntu, friggeri-cv

I'm using xelatex in ubuntu 14.04 enviroment. When I compile my file I get the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
!  
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

The file is a typical friggeri cv. How I can install Helvetica family in Ubuntu for compile this file?

Comment: Helvetica Neue Light is a proprietary font. If you don't already own it, you have to buy it or find a ***free*** clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install the font in `/usr/local/share/fonts` or `~/.fonts/`. For `xetex` run `fc-cache -fv` and for luatex `luaotfload-tool --update --force`. Maybe you have to run it as root, then use `sudo`

Comment: @Herbert I downloaded it and the copyright note in the font told differently. Of course I trashed the file before trying to use it.